# Compare two configuration properties (Debug & Release build)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to compare two different configurations in Visual Studio 2010. What would be the best way to compare the difference between two different settings (Debug|Release) in Visual Studio 2010 or 2013 as I have access to both development environments. Is there a way to get the configuration properties of both Debug and Release in command line so that I can compare them??

Comment: Compare the contents of the respective sections in the project's .VCXPROJ file.

Comment: At a minimum, you can go to the project properties under "Linker" and "C/C++" and copy the "Command Line" options to NotePad for each version.  Then, it's a matter of a visual eye scan of the contents.